# Hello, I am working on Alexa Skills to connect a skill to a .net core web API and I am getting an error if anyone can help me regarding this issue

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on alexa skills and I am getting an error when I try to return a response from an api...
The error I am facing from alexa developer console is:

I cannot resolve the hostname for the requested skill. The screen Capture is attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQoTg.png)

The Link to article that I am trying is:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/23/user-account-linking-alexa-aspnet-web-api#deploy-the-web-api-service-and-test-your-alexa-skill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle requests sent by Alexa, your web service must meet the following requirements:

1.The service must be accessible over the internet.

2.The service must accept HTTP requests on port 443.

3.The service must support HTTP over SSL/TLS, using an Amazon-trusted certificate. Your web service's domain name must be in the Subject Alternative Names (SANs) section of the certificate. For testing, you can provide a self-signed certificate. For more information, see About the SSL Options.

4.The service must verify that incoming requests come from Alexa. For more information, see Verify that the request was sent by Alexa.

5.The service must adhere to the Alexa Skills Kit interface.

More information can be found here:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#requirements-for-web-service